# Переход по ссылке после нажатия на LinkLable

Tags: c#

Почему данный метод работает на стационарном компьютере (Windows 10), а на ноутбуке (Windows 7) нет ?

Цель метода, при клике на `LinkLabel`, должен происходить переход по ссылке.

```
private void Zagolovok_label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://Site.com/" + z);
}// Переход по заголовку
```

Comment: Ну кто ж его знает? А сам метод хоть вызывается?

Comment: @VladD Да ёлы палы - опять перегрелся, смотрю в книгу и вижу "фигу". Не вызывался метод. Я его скопировал и вставил из другого места. Как всегда спасибо вам, перезагрузили.

Comment: Ну вот и хорошо. Одна голова хорошо, а две лучше.

Comment: @VladD - да, это здорово, что есть такое место, где люди готовы со знанием и опытом помогать !